# Exception in thread, function add number to array

Tags: java, arrays, numbers

I am trying to implement a simple function which adds a number to existing array but I am getting an error in the following code, an exception is exactly at function addArrayToNumber in line: "number+= NUMBERS_ARRAY[i]". I don't want to catch the exception, just repair code.

```
public class Main {

private static final int[] NUMBERS_ARRAY = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};


public static final void main(String[] args) {
    int x = addArrayToNumber(1);
    System.out.println("X = " + x);

    int y = addArrayToNumber(10);
    System.out.println("Y = " + y);

}

private static int addArrayToNumber(int number) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= NUMBERS_ARRAY.length; i++) {
        number += NUMBERS_ARRAY[i]; /** here it is */
    }

    return number;
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < NUMBERS_ARRAY.length; i++) {` you are going one beyond the end of the array.

Comment: Such simple mistake, thanks.

Comment: Got me by 12s. Yup, the most common mistakes are the simple ones. Pay attention to the stack trace, I bet it said ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, so naturally you should've checked bounds first.

Comment: Or, use `return IntStream.of(NUMBERS_ARRAY).sum();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array of n members has indices 0, 1, ..., n-1. However, in your for loop, you're testing `i <= NUMBERS_ARRAY.length`, meaning if array has length 5, you're trying to access NUMBERS_ARRAY[5], which obviously doesn't exist. Instead, use `i < NUMBERS_ARRAY.length`, so loop becomes

```
for(int i=0; i < NUMBERS_ARRAY.length; i++)
```

Alternatively, when you're looping over all elements you can use for-each syntax, i.e.

```
for (int element : NUMBERS_ARRAY) {
    number += element; /* add every element from NUMBERS_ARRAY to number */
}
```

and not think about indices at all.

Answer (score 0):

You get [IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) here because array length is bigger than last index by `1` in example array have elements [1,2,3] indexation starts from `0` and for get last element you need index `2`, not `3`, otherwise you get exception. According to this correct your code by replace `<=` to `<`:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < NUMBERS_ARRAY.length; i++) {
        number += NUMBERS_ARRAY[i]; 
 }
```